# Facebook CallbackManager is unable to call registeredCallback

Tags: android, facebook-sdk-4.0

I am trying to integrate FB Graph API to enable user to share the content on their FB wall.

On app launch user can login using the facebook button (LoginButton) which only uses read permission (to get the user name and picture).

Next when the user want to post a picture on their wall using my app; I create another instance of LoginButton and an instance to CallbackManager interface, then attach some code to that callbackManager (Code given below).

```
final LoginButton mLoginButton = new LoginButton(this);
mLoginButton.setPublishPermissions("publish_actions");
mPublishHandler = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
if (mPublishHandler != null) {
    mLoginButton.registerCallback(mPublishHandler, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {

        @Override
        public void onSuccess(LoginResult result) {
            // post picture code
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(FacebookException error) {
            Toast.makeText(MainScreen.this, error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancel() {
            Toast.makeText(MainScreen.this, "fb login was canceled", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
}
```

and the callback is invoked in the onActivityResult() method

```
if (mPublishHandler != null) {
    mPublishHandler.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

My problem is that when I tried to use the on the fly login button with publish permission; the facebook sdk cannot find the callback I set with even though it is returning success.

```
08-10 02:27:58.972: D/FacebookSDK.Response(4992): Response (raw)
08-10 02:27:58.972: D/FacebookSDK.Response(4992):   Size: 16
08-10 02:27:58.972: D/FacebookSDK.Response(4992):   Response:
08-10 02:27:58.972: D/FacebookSDK.Response(4992): {"success":true}
```

So, I tried to track the issue and find this problem occurring within the FB SDK -
(inside onActivityResult@com.facebook.internal.CallbackManagerImpl)

```
public boolean onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    Callback callback = callbacks.get(requestCode);
    if (callback != null) {
        return callback.onActivityResult(resultCode, data);
    }
    return runStaticCallback(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

Here the callback is a hashmap which facebook is probably using for storing callback instances(V) against requestCode(K). But I am getting requestCode as 64207 while checking the callback hashmap I can see that there is indeed an instance with key value 64206. Thus returning callback as null.

Any indication or hint is appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: I get this same issue if I do the same but the login is in a fragment.  The FB code example fails on the callback since its null but if I hard code the requestcode to 64206 it works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should call and register the callbackManger using the same variable

Also, call it in onActivityResult.

for example:

```
    public class Scene extends Activity {
        CallbackManager callbackManager;
        ShareDialog shareDialog;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
            lms = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
            callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
            shareDialog = new ShareDialog(this);
            // this part is optional
            shareDialog.registerCallback(callbackManager, new   FacebookCallback<Sharer.Result>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(Sharer.Result result) { print("onSuccess"); }

                @Override
                public void onCancel() { print("onCancel"); }

                @Override
                public void onError(FacebookException error) { print("onError"); }
            });
        }

        @Override
        protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
        {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
            callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        }


        private void share() {
            if (ShareDialog.canShow(ShareLinkContent.class)) {
                ShareLinkContent linkContent = new ShareLinkContent.Builder()
                    .setContentTitle("Hello Facebook")
                    .setContentDescription(
                        "The 'Hello Facebook' sample  showcases simple Facebook integration")
                    .setContentUrl(Uri.parse("http://developers.facebook.com/android"))
                    .build();

                shareDialog.show(linkContent);
            }
        }
    }
```